# Auto-restart apache2 on crash with systemd(Ubuntu 15.10)

Tags: ubuntu, systemd, sysvinit

There is no apache2.service file on ubuntu 15.10. I want to restart apache2 if the apache2 process gets killed. For most services I can add a

```
...
[Service]
Type=simple
ExecStart=/path/to/bin
Restart=on-failure
...
```

to the *.service file

If I enable apache2 as a systemd service I get:

```
systemctl enable apache2
apache2.service is not a native service, redirecting to systemd-sysv-install
Executing /lib/systemd/systemd-sysv-install enable apache2
```

So it's using the System V backward compatibility. Do I have to replace the /etc/init.d/apache2 script and create a "native systemd service" or is there any other solution?

Answer (score 4):

You should be able to run `sudo systemctl edit apache2.service` and enter custom overrides in the file, as follows:

```
[Service]
Restart=on-failure
```